# Is it possible to raise compile error on method's return type in annotation processing

Tags: java, annotations, annotation-processing, annotation-processor

For example, if you write override method with wrong return value.

```
new Runnable() {
  public int run() {

  }
};
```

Compiler will mark your return value `int` and give you the error 'The return type is incompatible with Runnable.run()'.

Now I'm writing an annotation processor, can I mark error on return value?

```
Messager.printMessage(Kind.ERROR, "return value error", /* which element here? */)
```

**EDIT**

Compile error is not only because annotation processing. But annotation processing can raise compile error. The question is how to mark error on method's return type. The answer may be 'It's possible' or 'It's impossible'. If it's possible, please help give a sample.

Comment: How is a compiler error related to an annotation?

Comment: @LutzHorn They are different. But they are associated because we can generate compile error by annotation processing. The question is how to get method's return type element. If it's impossible, you can answer 'It's impossible'.

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely possible. I'd use the `Tree` API.

```
// In your annotation processor you get it's instance using
// processingEnv
Trees trees = Trees.instance(env);
```

Now if you have to inspect your code using `TreePathScanner`. So e.g. get `TreePath` of your element:

```
TreePath path = trees.getPath(element);
```

And now traverse with your `TreePathScanner`:

```
new ReturnTypeCheckingScanner().scan(path, null);
```

And now your `TreePathScanner` implementation:

```
public class ReturnTypeCheckingScanner extends TreePathScanner<Void, Void> {

    @Override
    public Void visitMethod(MethodTree methodTree, Void aVoid) {
        Tree returnType = methodTree.getReturnType();
        if(invalidReturnType(returnType)) {
            trees.printMessage(
                ERROR,
                "Invalid return type",
                returnType,
                getCurrentPath().getCompilationUnit()
            );
        }
        return aVoid;
    }

}
```

Directly using `Messager` and `Element` API it should be possible too. But you have to figure out, how to get the element of ExecutableElement.getReturnType() (which is of type `TypeMirror`).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try it later. In my understand, `tool.jar` is from javac API. If I want to it also works in eclipse, I also need implement it in ECJ API. Am I right?